# RxJS - Buffer unique values and emit when no other values have been emitted for x seconds?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5, reactive-extensions-js

A user is typing values in a form and an event is emitted every time a user edits a particular field, with the value being the field they edited.

For example a user typing 3 times into the description field, followed by two times in the name field, would look like

> "description" => "description" => "description" => "name" => "name" => ...

I want to buffer *unique* values and emit them as an array when the user stops typing for *x* amount of seconds. A value *may* reappear again in a different buffer window.

Essentially this is to track which fields were updated when the user stopped typing and communicate with the server to save the edited values.

---

I have this so far which emits *every* 3000 ms, plus it doesn't prevent duplicates when buffering but instead we "deduplicate" the array afterwards.

```
   this.update$
      .bufferTime(3000)
      .filter(buffer => buffer.length > 0)
      .map(buffer => [...new Set(buffer)])
      .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

So it should listen until a value is emitted and then buffer **unique** values *until* no more values have been emitted for *x* seconds, then emit the buffer and repeat. How can one achieve this?

Comment: You ask whether this can be done without a custom operator, but you don't use one in your code. Could you elaborate on what your question is?

Comment: @Yoshi I'm unsure on how to do this in general, the code I gave solves a similar problem but not the same problem. I've removed the custom operator bit, hopefully the question is more clear now.

Comment: I'm still a bit lost, can you explain why/how your solution does not suffice? It seems to already do what you describe!?

Comment: @Yoshi My solution will emit the buffer every 3 seconds regardless of what's happening (I wanted to kind of push back the emission and only emit until no more values have been emitted for x seconds). Also my buffer was not unique and I had to manually go through and deduplicate it. See my answer below hopefully it's more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an alternate version:

```js
const { Observable } = Rx;

const log = (prefix) => (...args) => { console.log(prefix, ...args); };

const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

const updates$ = Observable
  .fromEvent(inputs, 'input')
  .pluck('target', 'id')
;

// wait x ms after last update
const flush$ = updates$.debounceTime(3000);

const buffered$ = updates$
  // use `distinct` without `keySelector`, but reset with flush$
  .distinct(null, flush$)
  
  // flush the buffer using flush$ as `notifier`
  .buffer(flush$)
;

buffered$.subscribe(log('buffered$ =>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@^5/dist/global/Rx.min.js"></script>

<div><input type="text" placeholder="foo" id="input.foo"></div>
<div><input type="text" placeholder="bar" id="input.bar"></div>
<div><input type="text" placeholder="baz" id="input.baz"></div>
```

Comment: I really like this, it saves me having to define the custom operator. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps my question wasn't clear enough, anyhow I've managed to solve it like so: (in case it helps someone else)

To have the buffer emit *only* when the stream was silent for 3 seconds, I start a new timer every time a user types something (event emitted on `update$`), and use `switchMap` to cancel the previous one.

```
this.update$
  .buffer(this.update$.switchMap(x => Observable.timer(3000)))
  .filter(buffer => buffer.length > 0)
  .map(buffer => [...new Set(buffer)])
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Then to get the buffer to be unique itself rather than having to manually deduplicate it, I had to create a custom operator `uniqueBuffer`.

```
this.update$
  .uniqueBuffer(this.update$.switchMap(x => Observable.timer(3000)))
  .filter(buffer => buffer.length > 0)
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

---

```
function uniqueBuffer(emitObservable) {
  return Observable.create(subscriber => {
    const source = this;
    const uniqueBuffer = new Set();

    const subscription = source.subscribe(value => {
      uniqueBuffer.add(value);
    });

    emitObservable.subscribe(emit => {
      subscriber.next([...uniqueBuffer]);
      uniqueBuffer.clear();
    })
  })
}

Observable.prototype.uniqueBuffer = uniqueBuffer;
```